# Ubuntu Laravel 5.5 images not shown

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Ubuntu 16.04, I have a project in Laravel 5.5 and I stored some images through script. The image files are stored into the path:

> root-of-laravelProject/stroage/app/public/

however, if I want to display them directly in the browser like : http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/image_1523525873.png , the images are not showing (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found). I also used this command : `php artisan storage:link` however, it shows:

> The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the following

```
rm -R public/storage
```

then

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: I run the command as sudo rm -R public/storage - which returns nothing. Now I run the command php artisan storage:link - which show me "symlink(): Permission denied".

Comment: When I run the command: rm -R storage
it shows that rm: cannot remove 'storage': Permission denied

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 public/storage` then `rm -R public/storage` then `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 storage - the command is working as I see that its returns nothing. but during php artisan storage:link it still shows [ErrorException]              
  symlink(): Permission denied

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara, when you execute `pwd` in terminal, what does it yield? Make sure you are running it from your project root.

Comment: ok then `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` and then `rm -R public/storage` then `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: removed the storage folder successfully. But when I use this command php artisan storage:link it shows :-- There is no existing directory at "/var/www/html/laravel-api/storage/logs"   
  and its not buildable: Permission denied

Comment: did you run `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` ? from within your project root ?

Comment: YES I run it sudo chmod -R 777 storage and storage folder has been deleted.

Comment: deleted? ok it needs to exist so `mkdir storage`

Comment: DONE, now the storage folder is exists but no content like log, framework, app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168815/discussion-between-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara-and-lucidlogic).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't automatically create a symbolic link using `php artisan storage:link`, create one manually from the terminal.

Go to your `<project>/public/` directory. Open terminal in that directory. And run the following command:

```
ln -s ../storage/app/public/
```

This will generate a symbolic link pointing to:
`<project>/storage/app/public/`

And if you still have issue with permission. Try with `sudo`:

```
sudo ln -s ../storage/app/public/
```